# SVG-specific CSS not loading in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I'm using the following CSS in my SVG:

```
line{
    stroke-linecap:round;
    stroke-width:4;
    stroke:url(#disabled); 
    fill:url(#disabled);
}
```

In Chrome and IE, this works fine.  However, Firefox won't accept the `stroke:url(#disabled);` and `fill:url(#disabled);`. So those elements are black.  I think that the `#` could be causing it (FF has had [issues with this in the past)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=658949).  What can I do to fix this?  I've tried escaping the `#` as well as replacing it with `&#35;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the `#` was a red herring.  (which is why escaping it didn't change anything.)  Firefox was trying to locate `#disabled` relative to the CSS file, rather than the SVG file.  I solved it by skipping the CSS classes altogether and editing the CSS inline with JavaScript.

Comment: That is what the CSS spec(s) prescribe for the url syntax, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri.